# Reference about the projective system

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

I want to study about the projective system and limit inverse.  Please let me know a good reference about it.

Comment: Are you talking about direct/inverse limits? if so, you can check Rotman's book "Advanced Modern Algebra" where in section 6.9 he discuss such topics.

Comment: yes! thank you @Xam

Comment: At what level ? For $p$-adic numbers, absolute Galois group, non-archimedean completion of number fields, pro-finite groups, adelic number theory, in general ?

Comment: for $p$-adic numbers. @reuns

Answer (score 1):

If you have the formal notion can see also the Atiyah-MacDonald's introduction to commutative algebra and read about the completion there they see the connection between these concepts